# calling getViewById in a class outside a Fragment generates null pointer exception and the content of

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, location, fragment, getview

I'm trying to change the text from a `TextView` that is in a `Fragment` when `onLocationChanged` function is called.

I know that i could implement `LocationListener` when creating `HomeFragment` but i want this to be modularized.

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    Log.i(TAG,"onLocationChanged method called");

    HomeFragment hf = new HomeFragment();

    if(hf == null)
    {
        Log.i(TAG,"hf is null");
    }
    else {
        if(hf.getView().findViewById(R.id.speed_box) == null)
        {
            Log.i(TAG,"findViewById failed");
        }
        else {
            TextView speedBox = (TextView) hf.getView().findViewById(R.id.speed_box);

            if (location == null) {
                if (speedBox != null) {
                    speedBox.setText("unknown m/s");
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "speedBox object is null");
                }
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "onLocationChanged method called, the speed is: " + location.getSpeed());
                float speed = location.getSpeed();

                if (speedBox != null) {
                    speedBox.setText(location.getSpeed() + " m/s");
                }
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "speedBox object is null");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create an instance of `HomeFragment`, but it's not attached to the layout yet, that's why you get `null` from `getView`.

The fragment needs to be attached to Activity by a transaction from `FragmentManager`, then `fragment.onCreateView` is called, then `getView` will not return null.

To me, the reason you don't want to use listener is not what it should be. Location callback should be global in a location-aware app, and any component needs to listen to location changed can register a listener anywhere.

Here is how I will implement it:

- Have a singleton `AppLocationManager` class that holds location logic, it keep the list of LocationListener and fire event to all listener if location changed. `AppLocationManager` doesn't need to know about its dependencies or what they are, it only does 1 job.
- `HomeFragment` registers the listener to `AppLocationManager` in `onCreateView`, listen to the change and update its TextView.
- Any other component can register listener to `AppLocationManager` if they want just like `HomeFragment`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you probably don't want to initialize every time your *Fragment class*, instead of that, you should instantiate this class only once and check accessibility of this Fragment, so a few options:

1. option - in this case, you instantiate Fragment class only once, and use this method as variable holder

   ```
   private HomeFragment hf; 

   public Fragment getHomeFragment() {
       if (hf == null) {
           hf = new HomeFragment();
       }
       return hf; 
   }
   ```
2. Find already visible fragment:

   ```
   Fragment currentFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
   if (currentFragment != null) {
       if (currentFragment instanceof HomeFragment) {
           //do your action
       }
   }
   ```

At least, try to post the whole class, where you have your onLocationChanged method